# Black Coalish Thing In Orange

Tags: food-safety

I recently found a piece of black substance in my Navel Orange. When I rubbed it against my finger, the blacked thing smeared on my finger like coal. It was less the 1 cm wide and kind of look like a jagged piece of gravel. Could anyone know what this could be?

Comment: I do not have an answer to what it is, but I ran into what I think is the same. Here's a picture of it, for future reference. [![black thing in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOH20.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOH20.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

If the substance was soft and smeared easily, as you describe, it was most likely mould - sometimes cells die in a part of the fruit, often through exterior damage, and these rapidly start to decompose. Left long enough, the whole fruit would have gone black. Harmless so long as you don't eat the section that's got black in it, and even if you consumed it, it's only a bit dodgy to eat for people who are mould sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like some form of plant disease. I am not a gardener, so I can't tell you which one, but many plant diseases create tumors or change plant tissue in other unpleasant ways.

A few byproducts of plant diseases can be toxic to humans. I wouldn't eat the orange. It is unlikely that you will get any acute symptoms if you already did, but in the long term, it is best to avoid such contaminants.